# How to make automatic and manual image slider in one page but in different image container?

Tags: javascript

I want to make 2 image sliders with 2 different image containers in one page. Top image container would be manual slider and bottom image slider would be automatic slider.

I took the code from W3Schools.com and did some changes to the code. I added ++slideIndex and setTimeout function but it still didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2 {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="img_band_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="img_band_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="img_band_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  if (n == undefined){
      n = ++slideIndex[no];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

The manual slider is working but the auto slider did not slide automatically. It just show the first image.

Comment: Can you please add the html part or share the link where you took the code.

Comment: @JayotiParkash I added the HTML part

Comment: Have you debug the code in console, it's giving error i.e Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at this point x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block"; because of slideIndex[no] 'no' is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here I added a separate code for the sliding the slider i.e carousel()

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex,1);
showSlides(slideIndex,2);

function plusSlides(n,type) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n,type);
}

function showSlides(n,type) {
  var i;
  if(type==1)
  {
  slideIndex = 1;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  }
  else
  {
    carousel();
  }
}

function carousel() {  
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2 {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">
  <h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/38/computer-768608_1280.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/shopping-online-payment-by-using-260nw-701873641.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/38/computer-768608_1280.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/shopping-online-payment-by-using-260nw-701873641.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Is there any way that we can make it in one function instead of two?

Comment: @eynamacho I edited the code to make it in one function. You can improve it more as per your requirement. Thanks

Comment: you are genius! Thank you so much! Really appreciate that @Jayoti